# how to replace the english statements by integer for classification problem

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a train data sheet like this:

| index | statement | index |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | Says the health care law rations care, like systems in Canada and Great Britain. | 0 |
| 1 | Obama has chosen to deny the vicious anti-Semitic motivation of the attack on a kosher Jewish grocery in Paris. | 1 |
| 2 | For the past year, I was censored and muzzled. | 0 |

Now I want to replace the statements by integers so that I can train a classification algorithm (KNN), how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is an NLP task. However, assuming you wish to stick to classic sklearn tools and not the complex language models, you may start with `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer` or `TfidfVectorizer`. It is still highly recommended to preprocess your text (convert to lowercase, exclude non-alphabetic symbols, lemmatize etc) to be able to get any decent results, so getting some basic experience with NLTK library might help you a great deal.

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2)) 
new_features = count_vect.fit_transform(df['preprocessed_text'])
```